# Why doesn't this import work using relative path package importing?

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

```
module_1.py
module_2.py
```

They are in the same directory.

module_1.py:

```
def print():
    print("module 1")
```

module_2.py:

```
import . module_1

def call():
    module_1.print()
```

I thought this should work from module_2 to import module_1 through relative path. But it doesn't work. I tried "import .module_1" and it didn't work either.

Comment: You don't have a package. Just remove the dot.

Comment: Removing the dot doesn't work either, it complains no module named 'module_1'

Comment: It sounds like a Python 2.X vs Python 3.X problem. If you are in 2.X, you might need an init file in the directory...not sure though,I don't use Python 2 anymore.

Comment: I am using Python 3.7.

Comment: What do you mean with "It doesn't work"? Do you get an import error or doesn't it do anything? Because in the code example you're not executing the `call()` function. If I reproduce your example on my machine, it works.